# Upload .nt/tdb file to protege

Tags: rdf, jena, protege, protege4, tdb

I am trying to load diff formats of ontology file like OWL, RDF , .nt, TDB.

I want to upload .nt/TDB file in protege. My nt(ntriple) file is in 40gb.
Will protege support this.

Comment: This question (along with a bit more in the way of details) would probably be a better fit for the Protege users mailing list.  What do you mean by a ".nt/TDB" file?  Is it an N-Triples file, or a file format used by TDB?

Comment: Yeah, I have an ontology in n-triple file format and another in TDB format. Is there any way that I can open this in protege.[EX: I tried example finance and pizza owl in protege, now I want to try these formats too.]

Comment: I don't know the TDB being a standard OWL or RDF serialization format, so I don't expect that Protégé will support it (although, its open source, so you could always add support…).  N-Triples and Turtle are standard formats, though, and you shouldn't have a problem with them, aside from the very large size of your file.

Comment: You've tagged this question with [tag:protege4] and Protégé 4.x is a desktop application.  In the question though, you say that you want to “upload” the ontology, which suggests that you might be using Web Protégé.  Are you using Protégé 4.x or Web Protégé?

Comment: I am using protege4.3.0(build 304), protege-core framework, not web protege. In this I want to open my .nt(N-triple) file. DO I no take any plugin for this?

Comment: TDB is a disk format use by Jena to do persistence. Your question is not clear at all, if you want to open a file in protegé just click File -> open and see what happen

Comment: In open Dialog, My file is not showing up.(Is it showing the file which are compatable to be selected to proetege?).

Comment: Is there any plug in avalable in protege to upload .nt file(n triple)